# "SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server

Tags: laravel, visual

hola tanto buscando para arreglar la relacion de muchos a muchos lo probe desde un proyecto desde cero y me marca este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desintale el odbc driver 13 lo instale lo mismo, probe con el 17 igual el mismo error estoy usando visual studio management 17.9 y laravel 5.8

Comment: El tipo de dato del id no es el mismo de la tabla foránea.

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia y como lo arreglaria?

Comment: Agrega el código (como texto, no como imagen) de la migración de esas dos tablas a la pregunta.

Comment: Mira el tipo de dato de la tabla principal y de la foránea y revisa que sean del mismo tipo.

Comment: ya arregle el problema lo que hice fue poner la tabla empleados le saque la S y cuando cree la tercera tabla la puse por orden alfabeticamente puse las relaciones lo corri y funciono